# Matlab Error in using pdist2 for high dimensional data

Tags: matlab, knn

I have a feature vector of 13 dimensions for m samples. I am trying to find k nearest neighbors of each sample.

I have selected the feature vector required.

```
[m,~] = size(featurevector);
X = [];
Y = [];
for i = 1: m-1
   if (featurevector(i,14) == 3)
      X = [X;featurevector(i,1:13)];
      Y = [Y;featurevector(i,1:13)];
   end
end
```

I have tried calculating the distances for each point

```
d = pdist2(X,Y,'euclidean');
```

It works fine till here. Now I wanted to find the k = 3 nearest neighbor indexes of each and every sample, so it tried

```
[idx,dist] = knnsearch(X,Y,'k',3,'distance','euclidean');
```

but it shows an error

```
Error using pdist2
       Too many input arguments.
Error in ExhaustiveSearcher/knnsearch (line 207)
   [dist,idx] = pdist2(obj.X,Y, distMetric, arg{:}, 'smallest',numNN);
Error in knnsearch (line 144)
   [idx, dist] = knnsearch(O,Y,'k',numNN, 'includeties',includeTies);
```

I have tried with example that mentioned in help . it works fine and I am not able to do when number of samples = 630. 
Did my coding went wrong ?

I am using Matlab 2015a
my paths on command

```
which -all pdist2
```

gives

```
c:\toolbox\classify\pdist2.m C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\toolbox\stats\stats\pdist2.m % Shadowed
```

any help appreciated !

Comment: As `which` clearly states, you have a function named `pdist2` in some classify toolbox which is shadowing the one that MATLAB ships with the stats toolbox

Comment: The indexing is working fine if i am selecting 10 dimensions. [n1,d1]=knnsearch(X(:,1:10),Y(:,1:10),'k',3,'distance','euclidean');
but beyond that it shows the stated above error. 
I didnt understand the comment you mentioned. Is there any way that I can get rid of the shadowing ?

Comment: There is a file at `c:\toolbox\classify\pdist2.m` that is being called instead of MATLAB's `pdist2`. Figure out how that file got there or remove that folder from your path so MATLAB can use the correct one.

Comment: Try also using `builtin` to call MATLAB's built-in `pdist2` to be sure that the problem is localized to a custom toolbox: `builtin('pdist2', ...');`

Comment: Suever it works when i have removed the folder c:\toolbox\classify\pdist2.m  . Thank you so much !